# How to access Sqlite Adapter class to MainActivity using Arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I am creating a sample gallery app, I am trying to store Gallery Items in local `sqlite` database

Methods for Adapter.class :

```
    public List<String> getImagePath()
{
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Databaseconnect.TABLE_FILE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {

            paths.add(cursor.getString(3).toString());
 //                Log.d("getPathImage:", cursor.getString(0).toString());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return paths;
}
```

than

```
    MuAdapter= new muadapter(Activityname.this);
    mudapter.open();
    ArrayList<String> list =getImagePath();
```

but I'm having an error On

```
    ArrayList<String> list =getImagePath();
```

How to initialize this method? Please Give me a solution.

Comment: share your logcat output

Comment: `fileManager` is null

Comment: sorry its filemangar is adapter name so i declared...

Comment: @vishnupalanivelM: Why not using `Adapter ` class object to access `getImagePath` method?

Comment: Actually , i need to display image set of particular path , so  i declared getImagepath in the Adapter,calss

Comment: MuAdapter muadapter= new  MuAdapter(Activityname.this);
mudapter.open();
ArrayList<String> list =mudapter.getImagePath(); if "getImagePath();" this method inside of MuAdapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MuAdapter= new muadapter(Activityname.this);
//  this line is broke. Use something like "MuAdapter muAdapter = new ..." 

mudapter.open();
// then this line can work

ArrayList<String> list =getImagePath();
// not sure about this, but don't you need an objectrefernece here, that you call getImagePath() on?!
```